# How to use *ngFor="let e of employees" within ng-options or ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have the following code

```
<select name='empId'>
     <option *ngFor="let e of employees" [value]="e.id"> {{e.name}}</option>
  </select>
```

The above code is working fine for static list of employees.

How to achieve dynamic select option from employees based on UI selection.

MyData

```
[
  {
    id:1
    name:"user1"
  },
  {
    id:2
    name:"user2"
  }
]
```

Comment: You can remove the `angularjs` tag

Comment: This code should work in case of Dynamic value too

Comment: @PardeepJain In my case the the option are not updated. employees is not bind to model still it work?

Comment: @Prabhakaran Can you please update your question with data?

Comment: @Prabhakaran yes please update your question by providing data and what you exactly need? Is the problem, that not all of the options are shown whenever `employees` is updated?

Comment: you might need to check your api does the employees object have an id and a name?

Comment: @Prabhakaran Here is an example on how a dropdown menu can be updated dynamically by only updating the `employees` property. The rest is done by the change detection mechanism of Angular.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dctycw

Comment: Thank you @Bajro

Answer (score 0):

There might be issue with data. Data should be in Inverted comma ("id":"1") format. Please try this.

```
[
  {
    "id":"1"
    "name":"user1"
  },
  {
    "id":"2"
    "name":"user2"
  }
]
```